# flutter appauth google auth 400 invalid_request

Tags: flutter, authorization, google-oauth

```
authorizationTokenRequest = AuthorizationTokenRequest(
          clientId,
         'com.socialauthexample.mobile_app:/oauth2redirect',
          issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
          scopes: ['email', 'profile'],
        );

final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result =
          await _appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
        authorizationTokenRequest,
      );
```

[image][image]

I'm trying to authorize via google in a flutter application using the flutter_appauth library and I get a 400 invalid_request error